# Parametrics Arc Length

Tags: parametric

Can anyone explain the difference between the arc length and total distance? I'm using the textbook [here](http://staff.howard.k12.md.us/~jmize/downloads/calc-abbc/FDWK_3ed_Ch10_pp530-561.pdf) and they seem to be the same formula. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same formula.

If a particle travel from a point $A$ to a point $B$ along a trajectory described by parametric functions $(x(t),y(t))$, than the ''total distance'' ( I prefer the term ''total path'') is the length of the arc $AB$, and the derivative in the formula of the arc length are the components of the velocity.